# How to pick only array types from union type

Tags: typescript, types, union-types

The question is if it is possible to do something like that:

```
type a = string[] | number[] | boolean
//here i want to pick only array types from a, to make b: string[] | number[]
type b = a
```

But it could be of type boolean[] | number[] | string. So that should work dynamically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use [the `Extract<T, U>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#extracttype-union) to filter the union `T` to only those members assignable to `U`:

```
type A = string[] | number[] | boolean

type B = Extract<A, any[]>;
// type B = string[] | number[]
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8UDOwBOBLAdgcwNoF0oAfKTAVwFsAjCVA4qKgeyYBsIBDTAWACg-QkKACEEUAKIAPNBwDGwADwwANFC4gCAPgDcfAPR6og6KMQoMOeiXLVaBIA)

Answer (score 0):

It can be done using generics

```
type A = string[] | number[] | boolean

type GetArrayTypes<T> = T extends any[] ? T : never;

type b = GetArrayTypes<A>;
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=5&ssc=27&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8UDOwBOBLAdgcwNoF0oAfKTAVwFsAjCVA4qKgeyYBsIBDTAKG9EigBxCMBipUHEABVwEJAB4pAPgRQpUCAA9gETABMkULiHoB%20NVABcpCADdaAbl79oVVcNHjJMyAphKHIA)